# Proper handling of form select list to rewritten URLs

Tags: php, javascript, html, accessibility

I have a homepage spec requiring two small forms, each with a `<select>` that allows a user to choose one of a number of "subjects" or "tags" and then be taken to a URL that looks like `http://example.com/subjects/selected-subject` or `http://example.com/tags/selected-tag`.  Internally, these rewritten URLs are actually `http://example.com/index.php?view=tags&id=selected-tag`.

If not for the rewritten URLs, I would do a straightforward GET from the form.  However, I'm now looking for a best practice way of implementing these in an accessible manner.

My first thought is to do a post-redirect-get to simply translate the form fields into a the beautified URL, but I'm wondering if there's another way to do this without requiring the intermediary redirect page.

My gut tells me to use the PRG, but I wonder if it can be done properly with javascript.  For accessibility reasons, I would rather not bind the `<select>` `onchange` to load the destination page.  Would it still be accessible if I instead bound the `<submit>` `onclick` to change `window.location.href` rather than truly submitting the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to implement both. Having javascript redirect the user using `window.location.href` is faster. For users with javascript disabled, the form will still work via PRG.